# How to get value inside div inside ul inside li with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not learning jQuery yet, so javascript please. here is the HTML like below

```
<ul style="position: absolute;">
    <li style="position: absolute;">
        <div role="checkbox" class="filter-list-cell filter-text css-ahhuez">
            <span class="dog-123" title="dogname">TEDDY</span>
            <span>8%</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="position: absolute;">
        <div role="checkbox" class="filter-list-cell filter-text css-voqwhr">
            <span class="dog-123" title="dogname">OZZY</span>
            <span>7%</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    .
    .
    .
    8 more <li>
</ul>
```

what i try to get is inside the li > span value "TEDDY" and next li > span "OZZY" and the rest of 8 more li value inside the span, make the result as a array like:

```
dogname = [TEDDY,OZZY,REX...]
```

i tried right click to copy selector path then use document.querySelectorAll(), i got 10 NodeList, i Array.from it but i still need to pass the div to get the span value.

i think i should loop through them? but it looks weird to me...
im not really familiar with html so please give me some hint or direction for this problem

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the js code you have so far?

Comment: I'm still using chrome dev tool try to find which area i need... not using any js right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the dogs by the `dog-123` class name, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the (converted to an array) node list to create a new array of names from each node's text content.

```js
const dogs = document.querySelectorAll('.dog-123');
const names = [...dogs].map(dog => dog.textContent);
console.log(names);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="dog-123">TEDDY</span>
    <span>8%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="dog-123">OZZY</span>
    <span>7%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="dog-123">Bob from Accounting</span>
    <span>700%</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors): grab the first `span` inside every `div` which is inside a `li` which is inside an `ul`. The [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) part is called a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), that is, it selects an element with respect not only to itself and its parents / siblings, but against characteristics of the XML tree or even external characteristics such as browser history.

Careful, though, because if you have another `ul` whose descendants have those characteristics, you would be selecting undesired values.

In one line:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li > div span:first-child")).map(x => x.innerText);
```

If you wanted to be more precise (in a scraper, for example), you would probably start with a root element with a known id (thence unique). So let's say you have `<ul id="myList">`, then the CSS selector would be `#myList > li > div span:first-child`.